# Using Switching Regulators to Make Split Supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, negative-voltage

I am trying to use two switch-mode regulators to create a split supply, where the first one regulates the positive voltage as per the application schematic in the datasheet and the second one works the same way, but references its output to GND and uses the GND pin as the negative voltage output. Is this valid? Here is my schematic:

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Forgetting the top half of that schematic... what do you think the bottom half is going to do wired that way?

Comment: I think that by using the system GND at its voltage output it will cause the regulator's GND reference to be pushed to -5V.

Comment: Vin of the lower regulator is connected to "GND". Where does it get its "-36V" from?

Comment: I see what you're saying - I believe I connected the inputs wrong. What about something like this: http://imgur.com/1AmKCFk

Comment: WHat you propose simply wont work.. Read photons answer.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make an LM2576 produce a negative regulated voltage - read the data sheet: -

[image]

You need to follow the circuit above to make it work this. A lot of buck regulators can be "pushed" into this mode of operation BTW such as this one from LT: -

[image]

Or this one: -

[image]

Some SEPIC controllers can also be used this way: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Must have missed this - guess I need to RTFM.

Comment: What does the "F" stand for LOL?

Comment: Usually something like "read the freaking manual"

Comment: Although you can force them, really it's better to use the right part for the job.