# 5v, 12v, -12v from 12v, 5A supply

Tags: power-supply

I need 5v, 12v, and -12v in my circuit. What would be the best way to get this from a 12v, 5A supply?

For 5v, I could use a regulator. Not too sure about -12v.

Comment: How much current do you need at -12 volts? That will decide what type of regulator to use.

Comment: I don't know exactly, but it will only be used to supply an op-amp, and a 10v signal (~40ma).

Comment: Switched capacitor ICs can achieve your current requirements, I think, and are pretty simple. That could get you \$ -12\:\text{V}\$ from your \$ +12\:\text{V}\$ rail. These are found both with and without a follow-on regulator. You don't need the follow-on, so look for simpler ones. Use "switched capacitor voltage converter" or something like that in a search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all the voltages you need from just a 5 V USB or an adapter, I would use [this board](https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-5-24V-to-Dual-Power-12V-5V-3-3V-USB-Boost-Linear-Regulator-Module-DIY-Kits/183251279062?hash=item2aaaa09cd6:g:EL8AAOSwJo5bEBGd)

[image]

Input: 5 to 24 V DC

Output: + 12 V, -12 V, + 5 V, - 5 V, +3.3 V
maximum output current: 300 mA per channel

You can buy these are a DIY kit or soldered and ready to use.

The design is based on a [Cuk converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%86uk_converter).

I have one and it does the job.
Much safe than an ATX supply as it cannot deliver so much current that wires will melt. It's short-circuit proof.

Comment: The problem is, I don't think 300mA is going to be enough for the 5v channel.

Comment: That's extremely easily solved by using an additional switched regulator module, for example: https://www.ebay.com/itm/5V-3A-Mini-Step-Down-Power-Supply-Module-DC-DC-Buck-Converter-Input-7-28V-9V-12V/112619038572?hash=item1a389e276c:g:fB8AAOSw0oBZ2h17 It can deliver 3 A at 5 V, is that enough? Yes you can connect both boards at the same time to your 12 V supply.

Comment: Could you please link me to one which is pre-soldered, and not on ebay? :)

Comment: Also, I notice that each supply has it's own GND terminal. Is that to say that they do not share a GND? For example, could I ground all elements in my circuit to the same GND terminal?

Comment: @B4039 All grounds are connected together, if this board had electrically separate grounds then it would be **much** more complex and expensive. You will have to figure out yourself where you can order a ready-made one.

Answer (score 2):

THe easiest way to deal with this is to get a used ATX PC power supply. They output everything that you need. Just ground the PSON wire.

Comment: Although this will work, I would not recommend to use an ATX supply as these can deliver very high currents. Make the wrong connection and your wires and components are fried :-(

Answer (score 1):

Check out 78XX series DC to DC regulators, they are drop in linear compatible and you can generate negative voltages as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've used this type of circuit to generate -12 volts from a positive supply: -

[image]

Add a 79L05 to produce - 5 volts and your done. If you decided you need higher power then consider this: -

[image]

[This Q&A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/325846/using-switching-regulators-to-make-split-supply) has a couple of other options.